# apache access log and do not log images

Tags: apache, logging

I have this log format for Apache

```
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/test_access_log "combined" env=!forwarded
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/test_access_log "proxy" env=forwarded
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^.*\..*\..*\..* forwarded
```

I do not want to log requested images files so I use this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.jpg$ jpg-image
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/test_access_log "combined" env=!jpg-image
```

The images requests keep getting logged until I comment these 2 lines:

```
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/test_access_log "combined" env=!forwarded
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/test_access_log "proxy" env=forwarded
```

It seems like an incompatibility with the forwarded and the jpg-image.
I hope somebody knows a shortcut to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , **customlog** can't get have 2 environment variables like specified in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog).

I fixed my problem with this configuration, I changed it for your needs :

```
 # setup logFormat
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy

 #####################
 ## Define variable ##

 #If variable X-Forwarded-For is define with an ip define forwarded=true  (maybe use a better pattern match ) 
 SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded

 # if the variable X-Forwarded-For is empty set variable noforwarded=true
 SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^$" noforwarded

 # If the URL request an jpg I set all variables (forwarded and noforwarded) to false
 SetEnvIf Request_URI \.jpg$ !forwarded !noforwarded

 ########################
 # Define the customlog #
 CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/test_access_log combined env=noforwarded
 CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/test_access_log proxy env=forwarded
```

So if the request URI is for an jpg the `CustomLog` never matches the criteria, all variable are set to `false`. Log format are OK because the forwarded variables are true only if it comes from a proxy and noforwarded is `true` only if the connection is initialized directly with the web server.

If you want a log file with ALL logs included jpg you can set an other variable , but this variable will never be change. like this :

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^$" noforwarded
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" full_forwarded

SetEnvIf Request_URI \.jpg$ !forwarded !noforwarded

# Define the customlog
customLog /var/log/virtualmin/test_access_log combined env=noforwarded
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/test_access_log proxy env=forwarded
customLog /var/log/virtualmin/FULL_access_log combined env=!full_forwarded
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/FULL_access_log proxy env=full_forwarded
```

I hope it can help, maybe you already found the solution, but for other people.